# If-Method returns wrong value after saving and loading object

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, serialization, deserialization

today i've occured some strange error, but i'll give my best to explain it because i can't solve it!

First of all thats the method which makes problems, BUT only after loading an object via FileInputStream!

The error is that it *returns false* instead of *returning true*, even when the searched object **is** in the *saved array*

```
    public boolean isCarOwned(String pName) {   //find Car in Array with pName
    for(int x = 0; x < carCount; x++) {     // carCount = array length
        if(carInv[x] != null) {             //check if array is empty
            if(carInv[x].getName() == pName) {  //check if car in array has pName
                return true;                
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

When i'm loading an Object with the following method the upper method won't work : (i'm also saving this object with an similar way (write instead if load Object) )

```
ObjectInputStream invLoad;
        try {
            invLoad = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("save/inv_data.bin"));
            Main.inv = (Inventory) invLoad.readObject();
            invLoad.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thats the Object i'm saving and loading:

```
 public Car(String pName, int pSpeed, int pSpace, int pPrice, String pCarIcon) {
name = pName;
speed = pSpeed;
space = pSpace;
price = pPrice;
carIcon = new ImageIcon(pCarIcon); }
```

And thats the "carInv" Array if this is important:

```
private Car carInv[] = new Car[10];
```

I apologize for this huge amount of code but i don't know where the error is, so i'm trying to give you all important information.

So thank you very much for reading all this, i hope you got an idea or solution for me.

Comment: Strings compared with .equals not with ==

Comment: Okay thank you, i'm going to try it, never had errors before serialization!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Problem solved! But if it's an duplicate, i can delete it of course! @YCF_L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public boolean isCarOwned(String pName) {   //find Car in Array with pName
    for(int x = 0; x < carCount; x++) {     // carCount = array length
        if(carInv[x] != null && carInv[x].equals(pName)) { // if x-th value is not null and is equal to pName
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The issue was that you were not using the `equals` method for comparing String objects. Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for further explanation